# Delphi editor shift-tab unindent not working for single lines

Tags: delphi, editor

In Delphi 11.3 IDE code editor, if I select two or more lines, I can use Tab to indent them all jointly, or Shift-Tab to unindent them.

However, if I just place the cursor before a single line, then Shift-Tab only moves the cursor backwards, and does not unindent that line of code.

Is there a way to get unindent action in this case?

The Key Mapping "Key mapping modules" is set to "Default", and "Current editor key mapping is also set to "Default keymapping".

Comment: I usually use Shift + Down Arrow to select lines which works for one or multiple lines.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug. Even <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> / <kbd>U</kbd> doesn't indent / unindent a single line of code.

But it will work when the complete line is selected though!

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. Why? When you have no text selected and you press TAB editor inserts a TAB character if use of TAB characters is enabled or specific number of empty spaced if use of TAB characters is disabled. in case of single line selected that line is replaced by a single TAB character. When you press SHIFT+TAB the editor is not deleting any TAB characters or equivalent number of empty spaces but instead only moves the cursor position to previous TAB character or left by specific number of empty spaces. Such functionality is common in many other text/code editors.

Comment: @SilverWarior On reflection, I'm starting to think you're right. I have been heavily using a Python IDE lately, and it does behave as I describe: Shift-Tab outdents the line regardless of where in the line the cursor is sitting.

Comment: @gwideman Perhaps you should suggest Embarcadero to add this feature to Delphi IDE. I can imagine scenarios where this would be useful. And at the same time I can imagine some difficulty that Embarcadero might ha in implementing this feature. You should make sure that when removing empty spaces using SHIT+TAB you don't also remove any other characters. This would require additional checking of individual characters when performing such action. Also you need to determine when such action could even be used. Can it be uses with our without previously selected text? ...

Comment: ... If with selected text I'm guessing only if the whole line is selected. But how do you determine that? From the editor point of view empty spaces are also part of the line. I guess you are beginning to understand difficulty of implementing something like this and why Embarcadro might not be highly motivated into adding this. But if you could provide a code example of how to do this in your suggestion it might increase their motivation in adding such functionality to Delphi.

Comment: @SilverWarior As I said, I use a Python IDE where, as I now see on testing, Tab and Shift-Tab are dedicated to "indent" and "outdent". The function applies to however many lines are selected. If some characters are selected in a single line, they don't get replaced, this selection just indicates "this is the line to indent or outdent".  I suspect the function of the tab key is settable in the IDE's config, but as just described I find pretty useful and not confusing.
I agree it gets awkward to implement if sometimes the tab key is supposed to actually insert a char or navigate.